# How to receive JSON string?

Tags: json, post, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET WEB API.

I want to receive and add to database jsonstring.

My model:

```
namespace sms.Models
{
    [JsonObject]
    public class MySMS
    {
        //[JsonProperty("id")]
        //public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("fromnumber")]
        public string FromNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("tonumber")]
        public string ToNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SMSController:

```
public void Post(JObject singleSMS)
{
    MySMS smska = singleSMS.ToObject<MySMS>();

    try
    {
        SMS_Repository.Add(smska);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented));
    }
}
```

and method from repository:

```
public static void Add(MySMS singleSMS)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    SimpleSMS newSMS = new SimpleSMS();
    newSMS.Name = singleSMS.Name;
    newSMS.Text = singleSMS.Text;
    newSMS.FromNumber = singleSMS.FromNumber;
    newSMS.ToNumber = singleSMS.ToNumber;

    db.SimpleSMS.InsertOnSubmit(newSMS);
    db.SubmitChanges();

}
```

Now, if i send POST request from Fiddler like this:

**localhost:25856/api/SMS**

with Request Body:

```
{"name":"name", "tonumber":"1", "fromnumber":"2", "text":"text"}
```

i have null reference exception over here:

```
MySMS smska = singleSMS.ToObject<MySMS>();
```

smska is `null`.

What is my mistake?

Comment: But what I must to do if I need to receive collection of smses??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting Content-Type: application/json in your Fiddler request.